# div content margin pushing container

Tags: html, css

I'm running into an issue that's really baffling me.

I have a container that I want to apply a background to an position it in the top right of the browser screen. The div inside has a top margin of 4em and this is pushing the container div.

CSS:

```
#container {
background: transparent url("../images/house-bg.png") top right no-repeat scroll;
}

#wrapper {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 4em auto 0;
    border: 10px solid #C3CF21;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #444;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #444;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">

            </div>
            <div id="main">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            &copy; Copyright <?php echo date("Y");?> Company, Inc.
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the margin of the wrapper to be inside the container div instead of outside.

I've tried multiple display properties and position properties to no avail. The only thing that fixes it is inserting an "`&nbsp;`" before the start of the #wrapper but there's got to be a CSS fix to this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add `overflow:hidden` in order to "close" the context within the `#container` div.

Here, http://jsfiddle.net/kQsPR/ try to remove `overflow:hidden` and it will behave as you describe.

This behavior is specified here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

> In a block formatting context, each
>   box's left outer edge touches the left
>   edge of the containing block (for
>   right-to-left formatting, right edges
>   touch). This is true even in the
>   presence of floats (although a box's
>   line boxes may shrink due to the
>   floats), unless the box establishes a
>   new block formatting context (in which
>   case the box itself may  become
>   narrower due to the floats).

And this is exactly what "overflow" other than "hidden" is capable of (establishing new formatting context), you could also do that by adding border-top to your #container element, for example.

Comment: Perhaps, you can also add overflow:auto, due to the overflow:hidden's dangerous nature (you may run into problems if you have elements positioned absolutely, or with negative margins.)

overflow:auto would be a safer option.

Comment: Perfect I used overflow:auto like you said and it worked. This is an issue i had never run into. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting I read the specification. Should this really be the default behavior for block element to ignore their child's margins? I think it makes more sense to have the parent respect the childs margins instead of collapsing over them... Any thoughts?

Comment: Parent doesn't ignore the child's margin. Their margins collapse. That means, that between two margin-top values the biggest applies: in my test case (http://jsfiddle.net/kQsPR/1/) it's a child's margin-top:10px (it's bigger than margin-top:0; – a default value for the parent.).

It is actually a very helpful feature (margin collapse) that allows you to write more general styling, especially typography oriented. It allows you to preserve vertical rhythm (http://webtypography.net/Rhythm_and_Proportion/Vertical_Motion/2.2.2/).

Comment: Thanks for the vertical rhythm comment, I've always wondered why this behaviour was default and now it suddenly makes sense. Although, it's a shame your link is now broken.

Comment: That's really unfortunate indeed :( That was a fantastic resource. You can probably look at google cached version or read on vertical rhythm elsewhere: https://www.google.com/#q=web+typography+vertical+rhythm

Comment: Has always seemed like a bug to me...

It's quite usual to make margins top and bottom on Hx's.  When an Hx appears as the first element in a container (Very usual), or even first element after body, body gets pushed down and any BG's will begin not at the top of the page...

But hey... Just used paddings on Hx's instead.